# Tapestry 4.1 - using a Script component with an external js

Tags: javascript, tapestry

Is it possible to use a @Script component to render a script tag pointing to a js file hosted on a different server?

Basically, I need to inject a script tag such as:

```
<script src="http://otherserver.com/script.js"></script>
```

but I need to have it render in the head, or at least before other tapestry scripts are rendered.

Thanks, Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [Shell component](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry4.1/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry/html/Shell.html) , it's easy:

```
Shell.get(cycle).includeAdditionalContent( myHtmlForHead );
```

Or write a simple component that does that and reuse it in your templates.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a Shell component to wrap all your other files:

```
<html jwcid="@Shell" delegate="ognl:new org.apache.tapestry.components.BlockRenderer(getComponent('scriptBlock'))">

  <span jwcid="scriptBlock@Block">
    <script src="http://otherserver.com/script.js"></script>
  </span>

  ...

</html>
```